# C# setting up a load testing console app to hit an api

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I am trying to build a console-app to load test and measure some time measurements of an API.

To call the API I have a do while loop which posts using the `HttpClient`. For each request I am creating a thread, fire and forget so I am not keeping a reference to the thread or awaiting anything.

What I find strange is. If I run a console app I manage to send 2000 request, if I run 2 console apps I send 4000 requests.

Why is this happening since I am not awaiting or delaying anything?

Comment: do you mean that you have to wait until all requests are executed?

Comment: no not really. I have a stopwatch that breaks the do while(true) loop once x minutes are reached. Its very hard to describe my problem but its like my console app is choking on the amount of threads created.

Comment: but app didn't exit? or I didn't understand question correctly...

Comment: App finishes, all methods are working. A do while loop creates a new thread that executes an API call. The thread is fire and forget.

Comment: So what's the problem? :-)

Comment: The application slows down as more threads are created. Sometimes evens stops posting to the API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182114/discussion-between-ingvar-and-thefreeman).